# how to write lucene date and time matching syntax

Tags: lucene

I have to fetch data based on the following matching conditions using lucene syntax:
- assetStatus is equal to "archive"
- assetDate is less than or equal to 09/29/2016 04:00.

i am trying like below condition:

assetStatus:archive AND assetDate less [09/29/2016 04:00]

but above condition not working.

please advise.

Comment: could you show your code?

Comment: "less" in not a keyword of the lucene QueryParser ([syntax documented here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Overview)), not sure where you got that idea. To index and search dates you will generally have to convert them to an appropriate format first, see [DateTools](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/DateTools.html).

Comment: assetDate value is stroed as string type ( e.g. 2018-02-02 04:00 ) and I tried something like <queryString>assetDate :[ TO 2018-02-02 04:00]</queryString> , but did not work.